# Symfony / FosUserBundle : encore password after create

Tags: symfony, fosuserbundle, symfony-3.4

I am using Symfony 3.4 and FOSUserBundle.
I created a Form in order to create new users, it works perfect but the password is stored in database as plaintext.

When i use the command "fos:user:create", I have no problem. Here is my security.yml config :

```
security:
    encoders:
        MyCompany\PimCoreBundle\Entity\User: bcrypt
```

-> Below is my User creation form :

```
$user = new User();

$formBuilder = $this->get('form.factory')->createBuilder(FormType::class, $user)
->add('username',      TextType::class)
->add('firstname',      TextType::class)
->add('lastname',     TextType::class)
->add('email',   TextType::class)
->add('password',    PasswordType::class)
->add('enabled',   CheckboxType::class, array('required' => false))
->add('save', SubmitType::class)
->getForm();

if ($request->isMethod('POST'))
{

$formBuilder->handleRequest($request);

if ($formBuilder->isValid())
{

    // HERE (I GUESS) :
    // I have to get password with $user->getPassword, encode it 
    // and then save it within $user->setPassword() ?

    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $em->persist($user);
    $em->flush();

    return $this->redirectToRoute('route_confirm_user_added');

}
}
```

I don't understand if I have to encode myself the password from the form and what class to use. Thanks for the help !

Comment: Take a look at the FOSUserBundle register controller to see how to create a new user.  Hint:  Among other things, you are expected to use the bundle's user manager class.  And yes the FOSUserBundle is highly (some might say excessively) engineered.

Comment: Just read the documentation! https://symfony.com/doc/current/security/password_encoding.html

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to tell that I've already try with no success (Cannot instantiate interface Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Encoder\UserPasswordEncoderInterface).

Comment: @Cerad I just did, I tried to use the fos_user.user_manager service with the updateUser() method. User is well created but same problem : password is not encoded. It seems it doesn't use the encoder, how to check that ?

Comment: @Paolito75 If you want to use the FOSUserBundle then follow the directions exactly until you have a working user system.  Which means using the built in registration system.  If you want to do things your own way then don't use the bundle or be prepared to spend considerable time going through the maze of classes introduced by the bundle.  Because even if you get past this point you will simply run into other issues.  I will however give you a hint.  Ask yourself what User::plainPassword might be used for.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the plainPassword instead of the password field.

I haven't tested it with the form but you can set the password in the controller after the form validation with that :

```
$user->setPlainPassword($password);
```

It should give you something like that in your controller :

```
if ($formBuilder->isValid())
{
    $password = $formBuilder['password']->getData();
    $user->setPlainPassword($password);
```

Hope it helped